# How to include list of abbreviations in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

In fact I want to include my list of abbreviations in my table of contents. But when I write my latex code this list of abbreviations isn't showed in the table of contents. I have used  `\nomenclature` which will automatically print that nomenclature in the list of abbreviations which were displayed using `\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of abbreviations}`. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{unnumberedtotoc}
\usepackage[automark,
plainheadsepline,
headsepline,
plainfootsepline,
footsepline,
markcase=ignoreupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\leftmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper,right=20mm,left=25mm,top=25mm, bottom=26mm,%
head=14.5pt,%<- new 
]{geometry}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Publications}
\addchap{Acknowledgement}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of abbreviations}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{state of art}
\lipsum
\chapter{theory}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: and for the list of tables and abbreviations ?

Comment: You can use the exact same approach as for `listoffigures`.

Comment: This is for list of figures \cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures how about abbreviations list ?

Comment: `\usepackage{tocbibind}` ...

Comment: Yes but what is the code after using this package \cleardoublepage \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listabbreviationname}  \listofabbreviations  because this one doesn't work

Comment: @twimo: Either use `\printnomenclature\cleardoublepage \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}` or use `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\renewcommand{\printnomenclature}{\begingroup\tocfile{\nomname}{lon}\endgroup}` in the preamble and remove the code from the other solution despite of `\listoffigures` and `\printnomenclature`.